# Guard canActivate runs before service is instantiated

Tags: angular, angular9, angular2-observables

This is quite possibly a very trivial problem, and I'm just picking up Angular 2+ coming from an AngularJS background.

In it's simplest, I'm implementing authentication into my angular 9 app and stumbling across an issue with my guard.

In my `authentication.service.ts` service I'm using a BehaviourSubject of type user, and I'm saving my User object in `localStorage` using this common library: https://github.com/cyrilletuzi/angular-async-local-storage

In my `authentication.service` constructor I'm doing something like this:

```
constructor(private request: RequestService, private storage: StorageMap) {
    this.storage.get('currentUser').subscribe((user: User) => {
      this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(user);
      this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
    });
  }
```

and my `isAuthenticated` method:

```
isAuthenticated() {
    return this.currentUserSubject.value;
  }
```

This works great, however, because storageMap is an observable it's taking a tiny amount of time to return, and thus when I try to check the user is authenticated in my guard:

```
canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    return this.authService.isAuthenticated();
  }
```

Unfortunately `this.currentUserSubject` is undefined. So the guard is running before the constructor in `authentication.service` has had a chance to instantiate properly.

Any points would be gratefully received.

**UPDATE:**

I think i'm getting closer (ish).

in my authentication.service my isAuthenticated method now looks like this (as suggested below)

```
isAuthenticated() {
return this.currentUser
  .pipe(filter(user => user));
```

}

Albeit, with an error: Arguement type user is not assignable to parameter type.

Also, if i change my return statement in canActivate:

```
canActivate(
next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
return this.authService.isAuthenticated();
```

}

But i get this in a console

Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'boolean | UrlTree'.
          Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'UrlTree': root, queryParams, fragment, queryParamMap

```
18     return this.authService.isAuthenticated();
```

Comment: can you provide info where you injected authentication-service?

Comment: Sure, it's imported in my core.module, which itself is imported from the main app.module.

Comment: can you give me a stackblitz?

Comment: Not easily...  it's essentially exactly the same as this: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/10/29/angular-7-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial. except, instead of using native localStorage i'm using an async library (as above).

Comment: put a console log in constructor of service and in guard, to make sure of sequence?

Comment: Have done, if i put a console log before i retrieve the user from storage it prints before the guard console.log, however, once i move of into the subscribe it prints after.

Comment: can we have a zoom call?

Comment: try a solution i posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `canActivate` method must return `Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree`.

As far as I can tell you're returning an object (user).

However, in your guard, you should use the observable instead of the subject.

```js
canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authService.currentUser.pipe(map(user => !!user));
  }
```

The double negation (`!!`) from the `map` operator will make the observable to return a boolean.

Comment: I assumed i could do this too, however currentUser isn't yet defined, so i just get TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

```
async isAuthenticated() {
    var res = await this.storage.get('currentUser').toPromise();
    return res;
}
```

Reason for behaviour you was facing is, the subscription is a asynchronous job. so class initialization got complete as soon as it called subscribe. Subscription's callback will be called later when it will have that data. Before call of your callback your got called.

Comment: What would the guard canActivate method look like?

Comment: I'm not following with using router.navigate in my authentication service.  This issue occurs when the user refreshes the page.

Comment: ahh now got it, try the changed solution mentioned above. please vote if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: you changed isAuthenticated method as i gave above?

Answer (score 0):

Guards get activated upon navigation, so just make sure you have the user set before you navigate to your post login page.

```
constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService, private router: Router) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.handleUserChange();
}

private handleUserChange(): void {
    this.authenticationService.currentUserSubject
    .pipe(filter(user => user)) // falsy value check
    .subscribe(user => 
    {
         // Navigate to post login
         this.router.navigate(['home-page']);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's fine, but this is an issue if a user is on an authenticated route and then they refresh the page.